# Disconnected recordset in C++

Tags: c++, ado, recordset

I am trying to open a disconnected recordset in C++ using ADO & SQL server.  Code is below.  If I run the code and do not close anything but leave all the connections open, works correctly.  If I try to disconnect the recordset (using PutRefActiveConnection) and close the connect object per the MS example, I get an error that the operation is not allowed on an open connection.  I tried cloning the record set but that throws up too.  Also tried executing PutRefActiveConnection, then close.  Also tried dymanic cursors.  Tried read only locks, optimistic and pessimistic locks.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Connection string :

Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=GCSQL\GFDB;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Initial catalog=GF_Trades;Trusted_Connection=yes;

Code:

```
try
{
ADODB::_ConnectionPtr   _conn;

hr = _conn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
_conn->CommandTimeout = 0;
_conn->ConnectionString = _mConnectionString.c_str();
_conn->Open(_conn->GetConnectionString(), "", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
hr = _mRecordSet.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));
hr = _mRecordSet->Open(_mQueryString.c_str(), _variant_t(_conn, true), ADODB::CursorTypeEnum::adOpenStatic, ADODB::LockTypeEnum::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText || ADODB::CursorLocationEnum::adUseClient);
if (hr != S_OK)
{
    _mRecordSet = NULL;
    _conn->Close();
    return;
}
_mRecordSet->PutRefActiveConnection(NULL);
_conn->Close();
}
catch (_com_error e)
{
    std::string s = e.Description();
    s.append("\n Connection std::string = ");
    s.append(_mConnectionString);
    std::cout << s << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding  _mRecordSet.Close() ?

Comment: Yeah that threw an error as soon as I tried to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was in the construction of the connection and the opening of the recordset.  Setting the cursor to the client side has to occur at the connection level, not as an option to opening the recordset.

```
            ADODB::_ConnectionPtr _conn;

            hr = _conn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
            _conn->CommandTimeout = 0;
            _conn->ConnectionString = _mConnectionString.c_str();
            _conn->CursorLocation = ADODB::adUseClient;
            _conn->Open(_conn->GetConnectionString(), "", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
            hr = _mRecordSet.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));
            hr = _mRecordSet->Open(_mQueryString.c_str(), _variant_t(_conn, true),
                ADODB::CursorTypeEnum::adOpenStatic, ADODB::LockTypeEnum::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);
            _mRecordSet->PutRefActiveConnection(NULL);
            _conn->Close();
            _conn = NULL;
        }
        catch (_com_error e)...
```

Comment: Why all those underscores at the start of a variable name

Comment: It's a hodgepodge of code from several years.  Some of it is still in Petzold's Hungarian notation.